# How to avoid accidental keyboard press while working over laptop

Tags: windows, keyboard

I am studying/reading book via laptop and in between I am working over my notebook/textbook for practice. Intermittently some keys gets pressed as i keep my notebook over my laptop keyboard ( I try hard not to do that). Is there any way of disabling the keyboard using some shortcut option or a software which can help ?

I tried googling around and the option to disable keyboard was mostly shown but it wasn't a one click thing and also required uninstalling the driver, which can get complicated. I thought this would be very common problem for people who are working over laptop and also having a notebook along with them

Note: I am using windows 10 and reading a pdf file inside. Also prefer not sitting on a desk which could have solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Windows, would locking the desktop with `Win+L` key combination work for you? You wouldn't be able to read the book after locking and would have to type the password upon unlock, but least doing so would prevent keys from executing commands. At worse, you would get a "Password Incorrect" message (which should be fine unless you have some sort of maximum login attempts).